# Вопрос по массиву объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Условие: Существует массив(длина: 4) футболистов (каждый футболист – это объект). Напишите функцию `addAbility(array)`, которая добавляет к каждому объекту массива функцию `run()`, при запуске которой выводится сообщение (“ИМЯ_ФУТБОЛИСТА is running”)

Вопрос: что я делаю не так? работа с объектами пока тяжеловата. Получается в массив функция записывается, но не срабатывает. Потому что видимо не вызывается нигде. Помогите пожалуйста.

```js
 var futbolists = [{
          name: 'arshavin',
          age: 25
      },
      {
          name: 'ronaldo',
          age: 31
            }, {
          name: 'messi',
          age: 28
      },
      {
          name: 'mbappe',
          age: 20
      }];
        
function addAbility(futbolists) {
    for (var i = 0; i < futbolists.length; i++) {
        futbolists[i].fun=key;
    }
}

var key = function run(){
    return alert(this.name + "is running");
}    

addAbility(futbolists);
```

Comment: дак напишите цикл и вызовите функцию?

Comment: на момент присвоения `futbolists[i].fun=key` `key` является `is not defined`, поэтому Ваш код не работает. Т.е. о наличии переменной `key` программа знает, но значения у `key` еще нет никакого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var futbolists = [{
          name: 'arshavin',
          age: 25
      },
      {
          name: 'ronaldo',
          age: 31
            }, {
          name: 'messi',
          age: 28
      },
      {
          name: 'mbappe',
          age: 20
      }];
        
function addAbility(futbolists) {
    for (var i = 0; i < futbolists.length; i++) {
        futbolists[i].run = key;
    }
}

var key = function run(){
    return alert(this.name + "is running");
}    

addAbility(futbolists);

for (var i = 0; i < futbolists.length; i++) {
  //вызываем функцию run() для каждого футболиста
  futbolists[i].run();
}
```

Comment: латыши бегут? :-D

Comment: у меня все бегут) только что-то никто не оценит мои тренерские способности))

Comment: По условию, нужно чтобы у каждого футболиста была функция `run`. В Вашей реализации такой функции у футболистов нет

Comment: Действительно, прошу простить, переписал функцию.